# Collect different functions to one delegate

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, delegates

I have different `functions` I want to be called from each other. They are all UI animations, one for rotate, one for scale, one for move, and so on. I wish to *chain* them, so at the end of a `coroutine` an event fires off if something else was subscribed. Currently I would have to create `delegates` for **all of them** which would make the code's extension unbearable. How to create a delegate - or a collection of delegates? - whose event can fire off a variety of functions?

**EDIT:**
The functions are not dependent on each other. Move moves only. Rotate rotates only and so on. 
Only one instance of `Move` or `Rotate` can effect on one component.

```
class MoveClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Move
    //to ensure only one mover coroutine can be active.
    public IEnumerator moveRoutine = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves a UnityEngine.GameObject from position A to position B over timeToReachDestination.
    /// Uses Coroutines.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from"></param>
    /// <param name="to"></param>
    /// <param name="overTime"></param>
    public void Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
    {
        //pull off this shit to ensure only once it will be executed.
        if (moveRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
        }
        moveRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime);
        StartCoroutine(moveRoutine);
        //StartCoroutine(_Move(from, to, overTime));
    }
    IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
    {
        Vector2 original = from.position;
        float timer = 0.0f;
        while (timer < overTime)
        {
            float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
            from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        if(event != null)
        {
            event(/*parameters*/);
            //or loop through the events?
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hello @agiro the functions have a dependency between each other? For example, to call the scale you should have called the rotate before, etc.?

Comment: Make a base one `MeEventArgs` and derive from it ( `MeTransformEventArgs` ). Then  you can use `public event MeEventHandler MeEvent;` where `MeEventHandler` is `public delegate void MeEventHandler(object sender, MeEventArgs)` and use it like `MeEvent(this, (MeEventArgs)new MeTransformEventArgs(...))`

Comment: Edited for clarification. @ErickGallani

Comment: @m.rogalski I'm trying to implement what you said, but it's currently a bit unclear to me. Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a callback at the end of your coroutine.

```
IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, Action /*<Parameter>*/ onCompletion = null)
{
    // Your current code

    if(onCompletion!= null)
    {
        onCompletion(/*parameters*/);
        //or loop through the events?
    }
}
```

EDIT: added onCompletion = null so it has default parameter.

Considering you may have different parameter list for the callback, you'd come up with various overloads. The common code would be move to a method that is called in all different overloads, only the last part would be different:

```
void MoveItem(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
{
     float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
     from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
}
IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, Action onCompletion = null)
{
    Vector2 original = from.position;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    while (timer < overTime)
    {
        MoveItem(from, to, overTime);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    if(event != null)
    {
        event();
    }
}

    IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, Action <float>onCompletion = null)
{
    Vector2 original = from.position;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    while (timer < overTime)
    {
        MoveItem(from, to, overTime);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    if(event != null)
    {
        event(10.0f);
    }
}
```

You could push the flexibility to provide a delegate for the MoveItem method so you can pass any movement method (shape of the movement could be either linear, exponential and so on).

Comment: Thanks for the info, though not entirely. I may or may not use another animation at the end, so I don't know how to handle with callbacks that I don't do anything else (pass a null?)

Comment: Yes, pass null or don't pass (I'm updating the answer to consider this case). If the delegate is null, it won't call.

Comment: Thanks. Now I knew what to do, if I had only _one_ other function to call, but I have many with different parameters. Shall I use different `_Move` functions for each possibility?

Comment: You'd have to use overload of the method to accept the different parameter list and call properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I keep these callbacks in mind, though I really wanted to avoid overloading these as I might add a lot more to the capabilities of this UI anim library :D

Comment: You somehow need to since you'd have to call the delegate with the appropriate parameters. You could pass default values but then there is no point anymore in having parameters. All in all, for different type of parameters, you'd have to go through overload.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining my comment in somewhat more detailed form.

You can make a global ( one ) `EventHandler` to fire from your code :

```
public delegate void MeEventHandler(object sender, MeEventArgs e);
```

Then as you expect you should make base `MeEventArgs` class :

```
public abstract class MeEventArgs
{
    // nothing in here or some common fields/properties
}
```

Next you derive from that on every way you like :

```
public sealed class MeTransformEventArgs
    : MeEventArgs
{
    public bool SuccesfullyTransformed { get; set; }
    public Vector3 PreviousPosition { get; set; }
    public Vector3 NewPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Same with rotate event :

```
public sealed class MeRotationEventArgs
    : MeEventArgs
{
    public bool Successfull { get; set; }
    public Quaternion FromAngle { get; set; }
    public Quaternion ToAngle { get; set; }
}
```

And the same with others...

Now you can make your event like :

```
public event MeEventHandler MeEvent;
```

And whenever you want to fire this event :

```
MeEvent(this, (MeEventArgs)new MeTransformEventArgs() { SuccesfullyTransformed = false, PreviousPosition = Vector3.zero, NewPosition = Vector3.zero });
```

Then you catch these using :

```
void WhenEventFired(object sender, MeEventArgs e)
{
    if(e is MeTransformEventArgs)
    {
        MeTransformEventArgs eArgs = (MeTransformEventArgs)e;
        // do something with event.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help as well on this one. I mark this page as a bookmark because actually both answers make sense and I learned a lot from both of them.

Comment: May I ask, why would we need the `sender`? I'm implementing something else where this solution is quite accurate. It's just unsure why we need to pass that, Could you tell me?

Comment: To be honest you don't have to specify sender. But the idea is to recognise object that sent this event. Making it simpler imagine you have 3 senders calling back the same handler. To then be able to recognise and identify sender you should have some reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a delegate - or a collection of delegates? - whose event can fire off a variety of functions?

Multicast delegates.

```
Action onCompletion = SomeMethod;
onCompletion += SomeOtherMethod;
// Now the delegate will call both methods when invoked.
StartCoroutine(_Move(..., onCompletion));
```

Or you could literally just make a collection of delegates, I.E. `List<Action>`.